# IPhone - Camera roll in app

Tags: iphone, camera

Do you know some way to show the camera roll in my app with navigation bar, backward, forward, delete controls??
Thankz :D

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the UIImagePickerController:

Example:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated: YES];
```

Dont forget to implement the delegate protocol.

Here is a link to Apple's docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html