# Open camera roll on an exact photo

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, photo, alassetslibrary

I'm developing a camera application where I'd like to put some functions that are already present in the stock app. My problem is replicating the little square in the bottom left corner (in portrait mode) where the micro-thumbnail of the photo that the user has just taken is shown; then, when the user tap on it, the photo app should open, on the last photo saved in the camera roll.

I can load the thumbnail of the newest photo in camera roll with ALAssetsLibrary - I've access to it with `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[result thumbnail]]` - but even if I have its ALAsset URL, I can't open the photo app. I'm trying to do it with:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:result.defaultRepresentation.url];
```

But nothing happens.

I could display it internally in my app, with an additional UIView, but I think will be simpler and... smarter to use the official photo app!

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the UIImagePickerController, as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11078182/883413

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772976

Comment: The picker is to display a list of photos, not to show a single picture.

Comment: thanks for the tip http://stackoverflow.com/users/419/kev I have updated the answer