# Open a saved image in camera roll programmatically - iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, camera

I am able to cature image (using AVFoundation), save image using assets library and save its asset url, open the camera roll programmatically using image picker.

What I want to do is, when I click on the a particular button, the last saved image of the camera roll should show up as if I had opened the camera roll and clicked on that image. I don't want to return the image object back to the program, i just want have a look at the image. And if I swipe on the screen, the camera roll images should scroll.

Also, can I do this using the saved asset url instead of just accessing the last saved image?

Also, If I press cancel there, i might want to return to the camera roll instead of my view controller. Would that be possible?

(I tried to search but i don't think i have the right keywords)

similar question here : [Open camera roll on an exact photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277292/open-camera-roll-on-an-exact-photo)
But no answer.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867496/get-last-image-from-photos-app) what you want?

Comment: Nope. I found this. But I don't want the 'image object', I want to open the view controller of the camera roll as if I have tapped on an image in camera roll.
Also, it would be good if I could overwrite/delete/edit the images I saved in the camera roll itself.

Comment: me too looking for the answer for this.

Comment: there is no way to do this I think. So there is an option we have. Custom it.